# Downloaded images has zero bytes in document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to download and store image from webURL to Document Directory.

Here is my code for that.

```
-(void)downloadPersonPhoto:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *imageUrlStr=[dict objectForKey:@"personPhoto"];
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"personAvatarStore"] isEqualToString:@"AMAZON"])
    {
        imageUrlStr = [imageUrlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"original" withString:@"100x100"];
    }
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [self getDocumentDirectory];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"personPhoto"];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
    }
    NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[dict valueForKey:@"personId"]]];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlStr]];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Avatar Photo stored at: %@", fullPath);
    }
}
```

Every time "Avatar photo stored at : ..." is going to print in console. But if I go to that path and check image then it has zero bytes of size and no any preview available.

 webURL of image is correct I can also check from web Browser.
I don't know where is mistake in my code.
Can you please help me to solve this??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` is not download image `asynchronously` from server. now if imagesize is big enough then it takes some time for downloading. and you are directly trying to store image to document directory. I think that create problem. you should use `NSUrlSession` for getting image and you should write data to local storage like documents directory from completion handler of `NSUrlSession` method call. you can use `AFNetworking` also to manage this kind od stuff.

Second thing use

```
 [data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

to store data to document directory and path is final path and should be unique for different data.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL]` is not a asynchronously method

if you Debug you code you will find `imagedata` will be nil

you should first get imagedata then store it

you can use `AFNetworing` , `SDWebImage` framework or just use `NSURLSession` download it

here's one solution of my own

`[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError * error) {
        //error
        if (error) {
            //handle error
            return;
        }
        if (data) {
            //store imagedata
            [data writeToFile:filepath atomically:NO];
        }
    }];`

good day :)